# Upload Attachment at the time of Record Creation

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment

I have a record, Intake.
When a VisualForce form is filled by an outside user, an Intake record is created when 'submit' is clicked, using the standard controller action 'save'. The user is then directed to a 'save successful' page.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" />
```

I would like to direct the user to a page where they can upload a file and relate it to the newly created record, and am not sure how to do this.

I am trying to use something similar to this VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="ContentController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" />
    <apex:commandbutton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and this Class:

```
public class ContentController {
    public blob file { get; set; }

    public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'testing upload';
        v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
        insert v;
        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the record ID from a newly created record? 
How can I then upload a file and relate it to that record ID?

Comment: Does it need to be an Attachment? Does a ContentVersion work and then introduce a ContentDocumentLink later to tie it to the record?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this is, but no, I suppose it doesn't need to be an attachment. Can you explain this to me further?

Comment: Salesforce Files (known as `ContentDocument` in the API) is the preferred approach to handling Files in Salesforce now (Attachments still exist but they're considerably older and limited). I would start by searching for `ContentDocument` and take a look at the [comparison documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5) that compares Files, CRM content, and Attachments together. An Attachment can only exist in relation to another record, so what I think you want to do in your approach is create the File _first_, then associate it with a record.